# Why do we constraint the input to Ord in the replicate function?

Tags: haskell

This is an example to rewrite the repeat function:

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

We only need to know how many times we are going to repeat the input. Why do we constraint the repeat number to be Ord? We don't care about the ordering, isn't it?

Comment: It is the *number of replicates* `n` that is restricted to `Ord`, not the elements to the list. And we *do* care about ordering, since we compare with `n <= 0`.

Comment: Oh, I thought `n<=0` is using `Eq`

Comment: No `Eq` only offers to check equality `==` and unequality `/=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the code, we see:

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

We thus check if `n` is less than or equal to `0`. We thus need an order relation for `n` since this defines when two elements of type `i` are ordered in such way that the former is less than or equal to the latter.

This function is one offered by the [**`Ord`** typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord):

> ```
> class Eq a => Ord a where
>     compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
>     (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
>     (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
>     (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
>     (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
>     max :: a -> a -> a
>     min :: a -> a -> a
> ```

Implementing `compare` or `(<=)` is however enough, since all other functions can be derived from implementing one of these two (in fact implementing one of the `(<)`, `(<=)`, `(>)`, and `(>=)` would in theory be sufficient, but here they opted to pick `(<=)` as implementation to derive from.